# Dynamically show forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Please I need help with this issue. I have a dynamic menu with buttons. Each button has name of form(VP,VZPAL,PAL,...).and when I click on some button, I want to activate form with the same name that the button has. I try do it with this code, but its escape with exception:

> Value cant be null.

```
string Formname = "FISpanel.Form" + b.Name.ToUpper().ToString();
Form frm =  (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(Formname));
frm.Show();
```

Value of Formname is `right(FISpanel.FormVP)`.Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using a type name instead of the type itself?

Comment: Probably, you passing wrong variable to Type.GetType method.
Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

Comment: Is the exception coming from the code you have here, or from the form itself?  That doesn't seem like an exception this code should throw.  Put it in a `try-catch` and debug it.

Comment: I changed code to 
` Form frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("FISpanel.Form" + b.Name.ToUpper()));`

but with same result:(

Comment: I would create a List of the forms and use Name for button text

Comment: What are your form name samples? As I understand, `FISpanel` should be the namespace you define your forms. If it's not, so that's your problem. `Form + b.Name` should be your form name, if `b.Name` is your form name, so `Form` should be a sub namespace under `FISpanel` and your correct string should be `"FISpanel.Form." + b.Name` (miss the period after `Form`).

Comment: yes,like you say before. My namespace is FISpanel and forms is like FormVP,FormVZPAL. but name of buttons is only VP,VZPAL.this is, why a puting together name of forms that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've achieved the same thing in the past. In my application I have 'links' that are set inside of .ini files, but these can be different for each user, so (like you), I needed a solution that would launch forms depending on what was clicked:

```
        LinkLabel lnk = (LinkLabel)sender;

        Type type = Type.GetType("Valhalla." + lnk.Tag.ToString());
        Form thisFrm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        // DISPLAY THE FORM //
        thisFrm.ShowDialog();
```

Also, as @King King has mentioned. The dot is very important. Are your forms actually named: "FormVP" Or just "VP" (etc...) If the later then you will have to call them as: Form.VP and not FormVP.