# assigning of forms by name dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So what I need is something like this. I want to call the web report form that corresponds to a variable. So for example if the variable value is Test. I want the test.aspx form to be called. I wonder if this is possible, so I don't have to switch between names of reports and assigning them to each and every form.

```
switch (reportName)
        {
            case reportName:
                report = new GWL.WebReports.Reports.reportName+".aspx"(); //<-- I need to evaluate something like this
                break;
        }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: it still is, because I can't just simply use this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275195/dynamically-show-forms

Comment: Perhaps you need to look up [the differences between Classic ASP and ASP.NET](http://www.bing.com/search?q=what%27s+the+difference+between+classic+asp+and+asp.net%3F&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=what%27s+the+difference+between+classic+asp+and+asp.net%3F&sc=0-30&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=a3fba9b419be4c748b4ef7b7bac4f6cd). Just remove the [tag:asp-classic] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out. I never knew that I can still use the approach that was used in my previous post..

```
 string reportName;
 Type CAType = Type.GetType("Namespace"+reportName);
 XtraReport report = (XtraReport)Activator.CreateInstance(CAType);
```